# Problems with static variables in Android Calculator code?

Tags: java, android

I'm programming a Android Calculator. I have all my code, but when use the calculator, it always prints "0.0", which is the original I set for total1 and total2.  So, my assumption is that the methods are not seeing those two variables. So I assume I have to set them as static variables so that the rest of my code can use them and change them. I may be setting up the static variable wrong. But after setting total1 and total2 as static variables, I still have the same problem. My other guess about why my program isn't working is my displayValue variable. In my if statement, it says that the local variable displayValue is not used. I would appreciate any help.

```
package rechee.cool;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public EditText display;
  String display1;
 double displayValue;

// I want to be able to use the following two variables everywhere in the code.
static double total1=0.0;
static double total2=0.0;


char theOperator;
public String buttonText;
public Button ButtonAdd, ButtonEqual, ButtonMultiply, ButtonDivide, ButtonMinus;







@Override
public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);




    if(display.length()!=0){
    String display1= display.getText().toString();
    // Says local variable displayValue has not been used. May be my problem?
    double displayValue= Double.parseDouble(display1);
}
}








    public void getOperator(String btnText){
        theOperator = btnText.charAt(0);



        total1+=displayValue;
        display.setText("");
    }







        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.bOne:

                    display.append("1");
                    break;
                case R.id.bTwo:

                    display.append("2");
                    break;
                case R.id.bThree:
                    display.append("3");
                    break;
                case R.id.bFour:
                    display.append("4");
                    break;
                case R.id.bFive:
                    display.append("5");
                    break;
                case R.id.bSix:
                    display.append("6");
                    break;

                case R.id.bSeven:
                    display.append("7");
                    break;
                case R.id.bEight:
                    display.append("8");
                    break;
                case R.id.bNine:
                    display.append("9");
                    break;
                case R.id.bZero:
                    display.append("0");
                    break;
                case R.id.bPoint:
                    display.append(".");
                    break;
                case R.id.bClear:
                    total2= 0.0;
                    display.setText("");
                    break;
                case R.id.bAdd:
                    buttonText="+";
                    ButtonAdd= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);

                    ButtonAdd.setText(buttonText);


                    getOperator(buttonText);
                    break;
                case R.id.bMinus:
                    buttonText="-";
                    ButtonMinus= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bMinus);
                    ButtonMinus.setText(buttonText);
                    getOperator(buttonText);
                    break;
                case R.id.bMultiply:
                    buttonText="*";
                    ButtonMultiply= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bMultiply);
                    ButtonMultiply.setText(buttonText);
                    getOperator(buttonText);
                    break;
                case R.id.bDivide:
                    buttonText="/";
                    ButtonDivide= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bDivide);
                    ButtonDivide.setText(buttonText);
                    getOperator(buttonText);
                    break;  
                case R.id.bEqual:


                    switch (theOperator){
                    case '+':
                    total2= total1 + displayValue;
                    break;
                    case '-':
                    total2= total1 - displayValue;
                    break;
                    case '*':
                    total2= total1 * displayValue;
                    break;
                    case '/':
                    total2= total1 / displayValue;
                    break;
                    }
                    display.setText(Double.toString(total2));
                    total1=0.0;
                    break;






                    }



                    }


}
```

Comment: why are you redeclaring displayValue variable in onCreate() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-declaring variables local only to the scope of `onCreate`. Try

```
display1 = display.getText().toString();
//   v ^ these now refer to the members of class HelloAndroidActivity
displayValue = Double.parseDouble(display1);
```

**Suggested reading**

- [Variables<sup>Oracle</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: So do I have to make displayValue a static variable too? Or is it not possible to make displayValue for the scope of the whole program? display1 isn't local only to OnCreate? is it?

Comment: @recheej yes it is. There is no need to re-state the type if you intend to refer to the class member. Only use `static` if you want the variable to be shared among all instances of a class. See update

Comment: Oh I understand. Because I was putting the type of variable in front of my variable, it was assigned as a new variable. I understand. But for some reason I'm still getting 0.0 as printed. Any where else in my code you see a problem?

Comment: @recheej Sorry, this site is for specific programming questions, not a free debugging session. Try printing values with `System.out.println` or use a debugger like Eclipse's to trace what is going wrong. If you can formulate a concise, well-tested question, come back with a new post and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not that much clear. You don't need to define them as static to use in same class. The real culprit in your code is displayValue. You never assigned value to displayValue instance variable which results value of displayValue as ZERO and assigns same to total1 & total2 variables.